# Deleting email using mailcore with imapSession

Tags: ios, email, swift

The following function works fine. However, deleting 1 mail takes about 4 seconds (from start of operation to the firing of the completion handler).

Currently, using `mailcore2`, copying mails on the Gmail server.

Are there any significant issues?

```
func deleteOnServer (indexSet: MCOIndexSet) {
     NSLog("will delete email")
     let sessionForOperation = getSessionForOperation()
     let localCopyMessageOperation = sessionForOperation.copyMessagesOperationWithFolder("INBOX", uids: indexSet, destFolder: account.trashFolderPath)
     localCopyMessageOperation!.start { (error, uidMapping) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                NSLog("error in deleting email : \(error.userInfo!)")
            } else {
                NSLog("email deleted")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My session is configured as follows:

```
    func createNewIMAPSessionWith(userName: String, hostname: String, oauth2Token: String) -> MCOIMAPSession {
        let retSession =  MCOIMAPSession()
        retSession.hostname = hostname
        retSession.port = 993
        retSession.username = userName
        retSession.OAuth2Token = oauth2Token
        retSession.authType = MCOAuthType.XOAuth2
        retSession.connectionType = MCOConnectionType.TLS
        retSession.maximumConnections = 2
        retSession.timeout = NSTimeInterval(60)
        retSession.allowsFolderConcurrentAccessEnabled = true

        return retSession
}
```

Comment: It will be very difficult to address your primary concerns with such little context provided.

Comment: @jamal May be I'm asking on the wrong site then. i don't believe xcode ship with libraries to interact with IMAP sessions out of the box. Hence, I believe my issue, if there is, is in the incorrect way of utilizing specific functions in the library Mailcore

Or perhaps my session configurations.

Comment: @nhgrif how may i provide more context? :) I'd love to learn to ask better questions.

Comment: Do you want a full review or are you only concerned with the slowness of `mailcore2`?

Comment: any feedback on the style of code / the way I asked the question will be be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about `mailcore2`, nor have you provided any Time Profiler information to help narrow down what takes so long to complete the action (is it just a slow network, or is it something in your code?  Anyone's guess), so I can't really address the slowness issue.  I also don't have a clue which methods are yours versus what you simply get from `mailcore2`, but with that said...

[`NSLog()` statements should almost always be wrapped in `#if DEBUG` and `#endif` statements.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28620693/2792531)

Moreover, regardless of whether or not the deletion is successfully, we need to let the user know one way or the other, and `NSLog()` isn't going to cut it.

I'm not sure how the second code snippet ties to the first, but all of our methods could use better names.

`deleteOnServer(indexSet:)` - delete what?  on which server?  What does index set represent?

---

`createNewIMAPSessionWith` - the words `New` and `With` can both be removed from this method.  Although, what would probably be best is simply creating a factory method:

```
extension MCOIMAPSession {
    class func session(userName: String, hostname: String, oauth2Token: String) -> MCOIMAPSession {
        // all the code you're already doing
    }
}
```

And then we call it simply like this:

```
let imapSession = MCOIMAPSession.session(userName:"username", hostname:"hostname", oauth2Token:"token")
```

---

> ```
> localCopyMessageOperation!.start
> ```

This is a pretty big no-no, in my opinion.  If the method we're calling to get `localCopyMessageOperation` returns an optional, then we should use *real* optional chaining, not forced unwrapping.  It's as simple as changing the exclamation point to a question mark and it prevents an "found nil when unwrapping" (or whatever it's called) exception.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback on the code style. :)

I think I had found the root cause of my issue here:

https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/issues/148#issuecomment-51481854

what should I do with this question then?